# Is there a way to convert the FILE_URI format into a File Object in Native Camera Plugin in Ionic?

Tags: android, angular, file, ionic-framework, ionic-native

This is an excerpt from native `CameraOptions` Ionic plugin interface.

```
DestinationType: {
  /** Return base64 encoded string. DATA_URL can be very memory intensive and cause app crashes or out of memory errors. Use FILE_URI or NATIVE_URI if possible */
  DATA_URL: number;
  /** Return file uri (content://media/external/images/media/2 for Android) */
  FILE_URI: number;
  /** Return native uri (eg. asset-library://... for iOS) */
  NATIVE_URI: number;
};
```

If I use `DATA_URL`, I see that the app is crashing when I try uploading a picture from camera or from the photo library. As they have mentioned "*`DATA_URL` can be very memory intensive and cause app crashes*", I want to use `FILE_URI`.

I tried doing this way

```
fileURI = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abc/cache/1586842420784.jpg'
const file = new File(fileURI, 'firstImage.jpg')
console.log('File Object', file)
```

But, the response is coming as below, all the fields are null.

```
{
   "name":"file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.slicktalks/cache/1586844010984.jpg",
   "localURL":"filename.png",
   "type":null,
   "lastModified":null,
   "lastModifiedDate":null,
   "size":0,
   "start":0,
   "end":0
}
```

I was expecting something in this format, a proper `File` object to send it to our backend API.

```
File {
   lastModified: 1582829787565
   lastModifiedDate: Thu Feb 27 2020 10:56:27 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) {}
   name: "TestImageAM.png"
   size: 186278
   type: "image/png"
   webkitRelativePath: ""
}
```

Could anyone please guide what I was doing wrong and point me in the correct direction? Appreciate your help.